# Is a hidden heading in the <footer> needed for accessibility?

Tags: html, accessibility, seo, semantics

Is it necessary or helpful for accessibility of my website to add a heading saying footer in the footer? I know the footer is a landmark en therefor a user of a screen reader could find out the heading 'Menu' is inside the footer. But using the heading list option of the screen reader this information is not present so a user doesn't know its in the footer? Any advice on this?

So should I do this:

```
<footer>
  <h2 class="visually-hidden">Footer</h2>
  <h3>Menu</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Or this:

```
<footer>
  <h2>Menu</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: The first code example with a visually hidden heading (<h2 class="visually-hidden">Footer</h2>) is a good practice for accessibility. However, if the "Menu" heading is the primary content of the footer, it might not be necessary to add an additional "Footer" heading, as "Menu" could suffice for understanding the content.

But either method is acceptable for accessibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/contentinfo_role) and [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/page-structure/regions/#page-footer) just having the `<footer>` tag by itself is enough to be accessible as long as it is not used inside an `<article>` or `<section>` element. The second option should be enough from an accessibility stand point.

Comment: If this is true the second code example on MDN is quite confusing:```<footer><h2>Footer</h2><!-- footer content --></footer>```

Answer (score 1):

`<footer>` is already a (very common) *tag* which screenreaders can interpret, so you don't need an additional (hidden) header for it.

Apart from that, also your "Menu" `<h2>` headers in both examples are not necessary – a `<nav>` tag around the `ul` menu or `role="navigation"` as an attribute in the `ul` is sufficient and actually more practical for screen reader users.